# How to test if a String is DBnull

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to find how to test if a String, from a database, is null or not.
Unfortunately, whatever i'm trying, i always find the same exception :
Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.

CuttingLength1 is a String property into TypedDataRow

```
Dim dsResults As TypedDataSet
Dim dtResults As TypedDataSet.TypedDataTable
Dim result As TypedDataSet.TypedDataTable.TypedDataRow
Using data As New Bl.Method(MetaData) 
    dsResults = data.GetData(parameter)
    dtResults = dsResults.Typed
    result = dtResults.First
    If (Not result Is Nothing) Then
        If Not result.CuttingLength1 Is Nothing Then
            'If Not (DBNull.Value.Equals(result.CuttingLength1)) Then
            'If Not IsDBNull(result.CuttingLength1) Then
            TextBoxM1.Text = result.CuttingLength1
        End If
    End If
End Using
```

I've also tried with expressions in captions

Comment: What is `result`?  What is `result.CuttingLength1`?  How are they related to `DBNull`?  Can you expand the sample code to demonstrate?

Comment: @David I've edited with more informations

Comment: Note that if the interface seems clunky, it's because typed datasets were developed before nullable value types, so at the time, it was the only way to deal with things like `Integer` that can't be null (in the .NET sense).  Otherwise, it would have been an obvious choice to map database nulls onto .NET nulls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a typed `DataSet`, so every typed `DataRow` has a dedicated method for each column to determine whether it is `NULL` or not. Your code should look something like this:

```vb
If Not result.IsCuttingLength1Null() Then
    TextBoxM1.Text = result.CuttingLength1
End If
```

You don't work directly with `DBNull` in a typed `DataSet`.

I think that's what the method will be named but, if not, it will be similar and Intellisense will show you. It may also be a property but I think it's a method. There is also a corresponding `SetCuttingLength1Null` method.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a string, it's not `DBNull`. That's the beauty of strong typing. It's just not possible to put a peg shaped like DBNull into a hole shaped like a string.

Comment: I understand but, why do I obtain the exception : "The value for column 'CuttingLength1' in table 'Typed' is DBNull."  even if it is a String ?

Comment: It probably fails trying to create the typed dataset before your code even runs. When you generate the class for the typed dataset, it needs to know the column might be nullable.

Comment: Do you mean that it is  required CuttingLength1 allows DBNull values ? It's already done

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `String.IsNullOrEmpty` function?

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.CuttingLength1) Then
    TextBoxM1.Text = result.CuttingLength1
End If
```

Comment: DBNull is a specific type from ADO.Net. It won't just come back as an empty object or zero length string.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply test whether the returned value is a `String`. `DBNull` is not a `String` and `Nothing` is not a string. Also, you can use the [?. null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) to handle `result` being `Nothing`:

```vb
If TypeOf result?.CuttingLength1 Is String Then
    TextBoxM1.Text = result.CuttingLength1
End If
```

Note: I assume that `CuttingLength1` despite its name is a Text column. Otherwise change the type test accordingly.

Comment: I don't think it's really correct to say that `Nothing` is not a `String`.  `Nothing` is the default value for any type, so there is definitely a `String`-flavored `Nothing`.  Unless the intended point is that for a reference type, null is a distinct state from having a value?

Comment: @Craig, the point is that with `Dim s As String = Nothing` `TypeOf s Is String` returns `False`. `Nothing` doesn't reference a string object and therefore it is not a `String`.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting.  I hadn't tried that before.  I would have thought that it would be `String`.

Comment: @Craig, VB uses `Nothing` as default value for a type and also as null reference. C# uses the `default` keyword for default values and `null` for null references. For reference types (`String` is a reference type) `default` is effectively `null`. For numeric types it is `0`, for Boolean it is `False` etc. This double nature of `Nothing` is a bit confusing in my eyes.

Comment: `default` is very useful with generics, there are things that are impossible to do without it.  If `Nothing` had meant `null` and not `default` in VB, there would need to be a new keyword to do the same thing.  It's usually close enough to refer to it as `null`, though, since it mainly matters for reference variables.